# Is there function in python to find out sum of time for a time series if its not in proper interval?

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ6M1.png)I am working on a time series data, where I need to subset the data based on certain value and find out the total time

After doing subsetting. I got some data from the 8th hour and some from 12th-hour. I need to find out the total time in minutes.

I want to figure it out the total time

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example for us, so we know what you are talking about?